# invalid token error on "01" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I have started learning today the python. And during my lecture on variables I found that whenever I try to **assign a value starting with 0** it gives:

```
syntax error :Invalid token
```

Like

```
zip=01290
zip=01
```

but when I tried simple

```
zip=0
```

it does not give any error.

I guess I am writing the code right because I have checked the syntax on internet.

Is it a problem in python or something else?

Comment: And there you have found another reason why you should only treat strings of digits as strings, not as numbers, unless you intend to do calculations with them.

Comment: why is it giving error??

Comment: Did you read the linked question/answer? `01` used to mean "octal 1" in Python 2. That syntax is no longer valid in Python 3.

Comment: P.S.: You shouldn't use `zip` as a variable name.  That's the name of a very handy [builtin](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Start a literal number with a '0', it interprets it as an octal number and you can't have an '9' in an octal number.